# How to change format of sql in SQL Task like in OLE DB Source

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Its very annoying to see that SSIS is replacing new line character in SQL in Execute SQL Task component. However it doesn't do same with SQL inside OLE DB Source component.

Update: Sorry for not clear initially. This is what I meant

This is how a big SQL with multiple lines looks in the designer of an `Execute SQL Task`.

[image: SQL of Execute SQL Task in designer]

When you see it in the Code/XML it is turned converted into single line with XML codes (`&#x`) which makes it not just hard to read but almost impossible to compare with older versions

[image: SQL of Execute SQL Task in code window]

Now if we use the same long SQL in OLE DB SOURCE of a DFT it looks this (looks proper without any issues)

[image: SQL of OLE DB source in designer]

Unlike in the `Execute SQL Task`,  SQL appears same in code window for this(see the new line characters are retained and SQL is not altered with XML codes)

[image]

Is there any way we can override this behavior so the the sql is stored in multiple lines which makes us easy to diff?

I am using SQL server 2014 and Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Your question is not clear!. Are you looking for SQL query formatter like (https://sqlformat.org) ?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.   Please post screenshots.

Comment: Never happened to me.Can you share some screenshots ??

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your "why" question - `Execute SQL Task` stores SQL text as an XML tag attribute, while `OLE DB Source` stores SQL text in text node. The former is more like legacy DTSX like SSIS 2005/2008 packages and the latter - more like DTSX of SSIS 2012+.
This is by MS design. If you need to compare two files looking for SQL commands - write an XSLT transform for the `Execute SQL Task` attribute, and compare/look through transform results.

Answer (score 0):

The `&#xA;` is the HTML entity for character 10, which is a line feed.  So the XML file does contain formatting information.  However, you are not intended to read or modify .dtsx files directly as XML.  Being hard to read or easy to manage with line-based version control is not a design consideration.

We've preferred to create VIEWs for each query, and then we've put the VIEW definition into version control as well as the .dtsx file.  This also has the advantage of being able to put the security settings for the proxy account in the SQL file.